# How to launch node script from anywhere in the commandline like Angular ng?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, command-line

I am working on a node module which does some stuff, i would like to run the command like Angular's ng command (it has to be compatible with Windows and Linux i have tried inspecting the angular cli module and make some modifications to my node module but it still doesn't seem to work)

Here is what i have done:

1. I have installed the node module globally via `npm install -g <nodemodule>`
2. The starting script has the correct shabang which is: `#!/usr/bin/env node` this is to make the command run in Linux without specifing `node`
3. I have removed the extension from the file which runs the command and it is something like this:

   #!/usr/bin/env node

   var cli = require('./cli/cli);

I am sure the script works, cause if i go in the directory and launch the script there, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already added `#!/usr/bin/env node` and set `chmod +x yourCommand.js` You only need to add:

```
"bin": {
  "your-command": "/path-to-your-command"
}
```

To the root of your module's `package.json`, [here](https://medium.com/netscape/a-guide-to-create-a-nodejs-command-line-package-c2166ad0452e) you can check  a good guide on how to do it.